# What are considered as outliers

Tags: r, outliers, boxplot

I am using this function to see, if I have outliers.

```
plot_continous <- function(dataset, variable) {
  var_name = eval(substitute(variable), eval(dataset))
  par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
  print(summary(var_name))
  boxplot(var_name, main = "Possible outliers")
  hist(var_name, main = "Distribution")
  possible_outliers <- (boxplot.stats(var_name)$out)
  print(possible_outliers)
  print(paste("Total possible outliers",length(possible_outliers)))
  table(possible_outliers)
}
```

The output is showing some outliers, but they are not extreme and can be possible data point. How should we deal these non extreme outliers. My output and plots are

> plot_continous(train_data, total.day.minutes)

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0   143.7   179.4   179.8   216.4   350.8 
 [1] 332.9 337.4 326.5 350.8 335.5  30.9  34.0 334.3 346.8  12.5  25.9   0.0   0.0  19.5 329.8   7.9
[17] 328.1  27.0  17.6 326.3 345.3   2.6   7.8  18.9  29.9
[1] "Total possible outliers 25"
possible_outliers
    0   2.6   7.8   7.9  12.5  17.6  18.9  19.5  25.9    27  29.9  30.9    34 326.3 326.5 328.1 329.8 
    2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
332.9 334.3 335.5 337.4 345.3 346.8 350.8 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

[image: box plot and hist]

Comment: It depends what is the goal of pointing outliers. Please clarify it.

Comment: I have to perform logistic regression. logistic regression is sensitive to outliers.

Comment: That does not make sense. The variable you show there is clearly not binary or between 0 and 1. Thus it is not something you'd model with logistic regression. Also, the distribution of variables is not relevant for regression. What is important is the residual distribution. Finally, those plots indicate no outliers. The distribution is only a bit heavier in its tails than the normal distribution.

Comment: @Roland This is not a target variable. It is one of the predictor and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: There is no assumption regarding predictors' distributions in regression. The only issue can be influential values. However, you test this after fitting the model as part of model diagnostics.

Comment: Few people would characterize any of these data as outliers.  The extremes merely show up separately on the boxplots because the dataset is large.